# (Code) What is the id in product.product in OpenERP v7?

Tags: python, function, odoo, product

I have create new column called product_unit_cost in Bill Of Materials in the Components tab.

### HERE IS MY FUNCTION:

```
def _get_unit_cost(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context):
        product_ids = self.pool.get('product.product').search(cr, uid, [('product_id', '=', uid)], context=context)
        prod = self.pool.get('product.product')
        prodobj = prod.browse(cr, uid, product_ids[0])
        res = prodobj.standard_price
        result = {}
        for id in ids:
            result[id] = res
        return result
```

### HERE IS MY COLUMN FIELD:

```
'product_unit_cost' : fields.function(_get_unit_cost, type='many2one', relation="product.product", string="Product Unit Cost"),
```

### HERE IS MY XML FILE:

```
 <page string="Components">
                            <field name="bom_lines" widget="one2many_list">
                                <tree string="Components" editable="bottom">
                                    <field name="product_id" context="{'default_supply_method':'produce'}" on_change="onchange_product_id(product_id, name)"/>
                                    <field name="product_qty"/>
                                    <field name="product_uom" on_change="onchange_uom(product_id, product_uom)" groups="product.group_uom"/>
                                    <field name="product_unit_cost"/>
                                    <field name="name" invisible="1"/>
                                    <field name="date_start"/>
                                    <field name="date_stop"/>
                                </tree>
                            </field>
                        </page>
```

### Then it show me this error when I run:

```
File "/home/henry/openerp/7.0_20-09-13/server/openerp/osv/expression.py", line 642, in __init__
    self.parse(cr, uid, context=context)
  File "/home/henry/openerp/7.0_20-09-13/server/openerp/osv/expression.py", line 806, in parse
    raise ValueError("Invalid field %r in leaf %r" % (left, str(leaf)))
ValueError: Invalid field 'product_id' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: ('product_id', '=', 1) on product_product (ctx: )>"
2013-11-05 02:25:13,890 8079 ERROR SydneyCakeHouseDB openerp.netsvc: Invalid field 'product_id' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: ('product_id', '=', 1) on product_product (ctx: )>"

ValueError: Invalid field 'product_id' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: ('product_id', '=', 1) on product_product (ctx: )>"
```

Please help! How can I get the id field in product.product? Please advise. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your function _get_unit_cost of your functional field. in this function you have written to search the model with condition [('product_id', '=', uid)]. But i am not sure why you are searching the product_id using user id. uid refers to the id of the current logged in user. If you want to get the id of the current product for which the functional field is being executed, you can simply use ids field. ie; you  can modify the code as:

```
def _get_unit_cost(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context):
    result = {}

    for bom_line_obj in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        result[bom_line_obj.id] = bom_line_obj.product_id.product_tmpl_id.standard_price or 0.00
    return result
```

Comment: Hi Prajul, thank you for reply.
I follow your modify code to change my current code, then it show me error (result[product_obj.id] = product.standard_price or 0.00
NameError: global name 'product' is not defined)

So, I try change your code again to:
`code`
result[product_obj.id] = product_obj.standard_price or 0.00

Then it show me this error:
`code`
AttributeError: "Field 'standard_price' does not exist in object 'browse_record(mrp.bom, 10043)'"

Please advise

Comment: Now I have change my code to:
`def _get_unit_cost(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context):
        result = {} 
        for product_obj in self.pool.get('product.product').browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            result[product_obj.id] = product_obj.standard_price or 0.00
        return result`

The error now show me is:
`AttributeError: 'Field standard_price not found in browse_record(product.product, 10043)'`

Comment: Its because the field standard_price is in the model product.template. The model product.product is inherited from product.template. So you have to fetch the field value as product_obj.product_tmpl_id.standard_price. ie; Change the code asdef _get_unit_cost(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context): result = {} for product_obj in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context): result[product_obj.id] = product_obj.product_tmpl_id.standard_price or 0.00 return result. i have edited my answer. Please refer that code.

Comment: Hi Prajul, thank you for your fast response.
I follow your logic and change my code but it give me this error:
`AttributeError: 'Field product_tmpl_id not found in browse_record(product.product, 10252)'`
Is it anything have missed out? Please advise.

Comment: THIS IS MY FUNCTION CODE:
`def _get_unit_cost(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context):
        result = {} 
        for product_obj in self.pool.get('product.product').browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            result[product_obj.id] = product_obj.product_tmpl_id.standard_price or 0.00
        return result`

Comment: Sorry. There was some error from my side. Since the product is in bom, you can get the result using the code def _get_unit_cost(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context):
    result = {}
    
    for bom_line_obj in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        result[bom_line_obj.id] = bom_line_obj.product_id.product_tmpl_id.standard_price or 0.00
    return result I have edited the answer also...

Comment: Thank you bro! You solve my issue. Again, thank you so much for your support and guidance! Bravo!